# hexadecimal string to usable hexadecimal in bytes()

Tags: python, string, hex, byte, encode

I need for my processing hexadecimals strings converted to hexadecimal. I do not want to encode it.
Example:
My progam (solving a different problem) delivers me the string  `result = ["0xa0", "0xb4"]`. Now I want to use 0xa0 directly as a hexadecimal in bytes like `bytes([result[0], results[1])`. But this is not possible ... Does anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fundamental confusion here, "hexadecimal" isn't a type. The `bytes` constructor takes a sequence of int objects. You can convert those strings to the integer of the hexadecimal number they represent using the `int` constructor (by passing it the base), and passing a mapping of that operation to the `bytes` constructor:

```
>>> result = ["0xa0", "0xb4"]
>>> bytes([int(x, 16) for x in result])
b'\xa0\xb4'
```

I *suspect* that wherever you created `result` you used `hex(x)` on some `int` unnecessarily. It's probably better to just *not do that to begin with*.